# Correct implementation promises with Node using es6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm starting in Node and i don't know, how i can implement promises in this example

- read array pokemons
- request data using api pokemon
- write response in new files

**Node** : `v6.1.0`

**ES6**

I have this code

```
const fs = require('fs')
const request = require('request')
const arrPokemon = new Array('charmander','nidorino')

function writeResponse(name, content) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         fs.writeFile(name, content, function (err, res) {
             if (err) return reject(err)
             return resolve(res)
         })
    })
}

pokemon = (name) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+name, function (err, res, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            console.log(body)
            return resolve(body)
        })
    })
}

function readPokemon() {
    for(var i= 0; i < arrPokemon.length; i++) {
        console.log(arrPokemon[i])
        pokemon(arrPokemon[i])
        .then(responses => writeResponse('pokemon-' + i, responses))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}

readPokemon()
```

I understand the concept the [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa), but is dificult for me implement promises in this example.

Error:

> Create a file `pokemon-2` but I need create a file for each response

Comment: With the code you've provided your Promises are implemented correctly so I'm not sure where the question is?

Comment: yes,but my execute don't work fine 'readPokemon' @peteb

Comment: Why did you remove the error message?

Comment: Is _"Create a file `pokemon-2` but I need create a file for each response"_ the error message? It doesn't sound like one, but is clearly labelled as such in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the asynchronous execution paired with the for loop. When execution gets to the part where you call `writeResponse`, the loop variable `i` has been incremented to 2, so all `writeResponse` calls effectively get `arrPokemon[2]` as their first parameter.

For a quick fix you could try something like this:

```
for(let i= 0; i < arrPokemon.length;i++){
  console.log(arrPokemon[i])
  pokemon(arrPokemon[i]).then(responses => writeResponse(arrPokemon[i],responses)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: yes but, create a file `pokemon-2` but i need create a file for each response

Comment: That's what this does. I ran the code with this change and results are like you wanted.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, updated. Not intimately familiar with all ES6 features yet.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*:

- Change  `function pokemon(){}` --> `pokemon()=>{}`
- Change var `for(var i ...)`  --> `for(let i)`